# data replication from a production web server back to the staging web server

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, replication

Have two web servers, development/staging and production.  Code and some documentation is moved from the staging area to production either through on-demand jobs or nightly via a global replication job.  The production server of course sits isolated in a DMZ.  There is some content that gets uploaded to the live server that needs to be replicated back to staging. Our security team is locking the network down (and they should) and restricting access to the live server.  Best suggestions for replication of "live" data back to "stage" and backing up the live server also.

Answer (score 0):

If the transferred data is strictly Unicode conforming text, then you might consider "down-shifting" the data to UTF-7. This will the data is strictly 7-bit (and no encoding or conversion takes place), it should ensure that only non-executable text is being transferred (versus most executable binaries is typically some form or function of 8-bit data).